# Как программно нажать в игре enter на активной кнопке

Tags: c#, winapi

Есть такая замечательная игра World of Tanks, как в этой игре с помощью программы на С# нажать активную кнопку. Вернее как послать в эту игру кнопку enter чтобы то что было активно нажалось. Пробовала вот так, но не срабатывает:

```
// Get a handle to an application window.
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
    string lpWindowName);

// Activate an application window.
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

// Send a series of key presses to the Calculator application.
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get a handle to the Calculator application. The window class
    // and window name were obtained using the Spy++ tool.
    IntPtr calculatorHandle = FindWindow(null,"WoT Client");

    // Verify that Calculator is a running process.
    if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Calculator is not running.");
        return;
    }

    // Make Calculator the foreground application and send it 
    // a set of calculations.
    SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);

    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
}
```

Comment: А можно узнать зачем все это делать? Насколько мне известно, это против правил компании и самой игры. Бан не за горами)

Comment: @YuriiManziuk прав... Но а так по вопросу, если ENTER нажать в самой игре, это срабатывает?

Comment: Бан за это не схлопочешь это раз, если интер нажать с клавиатуры всё работает, а программно с кодом  выше не работает

Comment: Данный код находит и делает активным окно клиента. И посылает туда Enter. Но что именно в данный момент активно в этом окне? Вероятно, нужно найти нужную кнопку и сделать её активной. Попробуйте утилиту Spy++, чтобы найти нужный элемент.

Comment: Там интерфейс на флеше по моему. Нажатие так просто не пробрасывается.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу. Т.к. WoT - это ужасный микс на питоне, флеше и плюсах - любопытно как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ну, если так, то SendKeys бесполезен. И Spy++ не поможет. Идея: спаять на Ардуине робота, который будет возить мышку по столу, прикрутить распознавание образов с видеокамеры, смотрящей на монитор...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Вы приудмали новое поколение бота, за такое даже банить не будут)))) А если серьезно - сделали как то в ботах и модах под WoT автовход. Это реально. Остается открытым вопрос - как именно?)

Comment: @All, неужели лучшие умы RU SO незнают как выйти из положения? Не хотелось бы забрасывать вопрос.